# Pólya urn model and counting 'successes'

Tags: probability, polya-urn-model

Let's consider the Pólya urn model. Inside an urn there are two kinds of balls in two different colours - black and white (b - the amount of black ones, w - the amount of white ones.)
We draw one ball, then put it back with and add $d$ more balls in the same colour.
For example:
the possibility of drawing a white ball is equal to:
1) $P_1^w =\frac{w}{b+w}$ in the first draw,
2) $P_2^w = \frac{b+d}{b+w+d}$ in the second draw.
And so on.
I am to find out the possibility of extraction exactly $k$ black balls in $n$ trials.
I thought of using Bernoullie's scheme:
$$P(S_n = k) = {n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
where the success is pulling out the black ball of course.
There is a problem however. It is easy to say how the denominator changes after each extraction, the k-th denomitor will look like this:
$$p_k = \frac{\alpha}{b+w+(k-1)d}$$
The counter is the problem. I think that:
$$p_k^b = \frac{b + md}{b+w+(k-1)d}$$
where $m$ can be any number from the set $\{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,...k-1\}$
I would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Polya’s urn give rise to [exchangeable sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables)--- conceptually the probability measure of the outcome is invariant under permutation.  For example, let $W_t$ and $B_t$ be the event that the $t$-th draw is white and black respectively, then observing $2$ white balls in $3$ draws
is same regardless of the sequence it is observed:
\begin{align}
\Pr[W_1W_2B_3] = \frac{w}{w+b}\frac{w+d}{w+b+d}\frac{b}{w+b+2d}\\
=\Pr[W_1B_2W_3] = \frac{w}{w+b}\frac{b}{w+b+d}\frac{w+d}{w+b+2d}\\
=\Pr[B_1W_2W_3] = \frac{b}{w+b}\frac{w}{w+b+d}\frac{w+d}{w+b+2d}.
\end{align}

Therefore, observing $k$ black balls in $n$ draws is equal to
$$\sum_{\text{possible sequence}}\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (b+id)\cdot \prod_{j=0}^{n-k-1} (w+jd)}{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (w+b+id)} = {n\choose k}\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (b+id)\cdot \prod_{j=0}^{n-k-1} (w+jd)}{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (w+b+id)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! At the end I figured it out myself and our solutions are the same so it must be correct. Thanks once again! :)